# How to get linux computer listed under a Windows Server Active Directory Computers

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, active-directory, redhat

I am able to get several of my RedHat machines to join my Windows Server 2008 Active Directory and am able to log into them with my registered users in the domain.  However, for some reason, they aren't listed under Server Manager -> Roles -> Active Directory Domain Services -> Active Directory Users and Computers > domain name > Computers. Only the Windows computers are listed there. Is this normal? Is there a procedure to get it listed there?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you joining them to the domain?

Comment: I configured them in System -> Administration -> Authentication and have my Windows Server as a NTP Server.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure on the specifics of the Redhat GUI means of configuring this, but my hunch is that it's set up to only use LDAP instead of using LDAP **and** Kerberos. In order to get the Computer objects to show up in ADUC, you need to do a proper AD join using Samba and the `net ads join` command.